# read continues to block despite pipe closure

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, posix

First of all, be prepared to see some magic.
Hi, I have been frustrated and struggling at this problem for the past hours and I can't understand why the child processes are not dying. I basically have one single parent process and many children processes. All of the children need to communicate with the parent and the parent needs to communicate with all of the children. For starters, I just have the children continually attempt to `read`, but my parent sends nothing and just closes the `write` end of the pipe, thus causing their `reads` to stop blocking. Here is my process (my macro def is `5` children processes):

Begin by creating an array of `5 int*` that point to `2` pipes. The parent uses the first one to talk to the child and the child uses the second one

Fork `5` children and close the appropiate ends of the pipe

Each child continually attempts to read

Parent closes all write end of the pipes, so the `read` loop in the children should terminate

Parent awaits child deaths

Parent dies

Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define PROCESSES 5


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int * pipes[PROCESSES];
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        pipes[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) == -1) {
            perror("Error piping");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //PIDS we will wait on
    int children_pids[PROCESSES];

    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        int status = fork();
        switch(status) {
            case -1:
                perror("Error forking a child");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                //Close the pipes we don't need
                close(pipes[i][1]);
                //Inside the child process, die immediately
                char buffer[128] = "";
                while (read(pipes[i][0], buffer, 127) > 0) {
                    //Keep reading and doing nothing
                }
                printf("Dying\n");
                exit(1);
            default:
                //Parent process, close the pipes we don't need
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                break;
        }
        //Parent continue spawning children
        children_pids[i] = status;
    }

    //CLOSE ALL PIPES FROM PARENT TO CHILDREN------------
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        if (close(pipes[i][1]) == -1) {
            perror("Error closing a pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //AWAIT CHILDREN DEATHS
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        wait(&children_pids[i]);
    }
    printf("All children have died");
    return 0;
}
```

I **know** that it is the `read` loop in the children that is blocking the children from dying because when it is removed, it works fine. However, I can't figure out why this is the case. In my loop at the bottom, I clearly close all the pipes and even check for errors. Why is this?! How is `read` still standing in  my way from accomplishing my `return;` goal??!?

Comment: Each chile has a `dup`ed fd... so closing the "writing end" doesn't close it in the child process fd until all child processes closed the writing end it too... You should close the writing end in the child processes when you fork, dropping the reference count back to 1.

Comment: @Myst, OP does close those: `close(pipes[i][1]);`

Comment: @SergeyA  - only one of them is closed. OP should close for each `i`

Comment: @Myst, oh, yes-yes-yes!!! Failed to see this, been puzzled by this. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: It's a bit ... odd ... to allocate the space for your FDs dynamically when you could instead just declare `int pipes[PROCESSES][2];`.  You could then use `pipes[i]` exactly as you already do, except for not `malloc()`ing them (and not feeling bad about failing to `free()` them).

Comment: Just curious, but why does this cause the read in each individual child to block? read is on the specific pipe (not all of them) and I do in fact close all of them (from the parent) eventually

Comment: Tip: `sudo lsof -p child-pid` lists all file descriptors that the child process has open, it's an excellent debugging aid to find file descriptor leaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I'll review some information that you obviously know. I write this since others might read this answer too and because it's always good to have some context for the answer.

Afterwards I will show why your code at:

```
case 0: // the child process
    close(pipes[i][1]); // <- if (i == 2) pipes[1][1] is open.
```

Probably meant to have performed the following task:

```
case 0: // the child process
    // close all input endpoints (input only performed by root process)
    // also close all irrelevant output endpoints:
    for (int j = 0; j < PROCESSES; j++){
      close(pipes[j][1]);
      if(j != i)
        close(pipes[j][0]);
    }
```

As you well know, each child process receives a `dup`ed copy of the file descriptor (fd) and each `pipe` is comprised of two file descriptors, one for input (reading) and the other for output (writing).

Each time you fork the process, both of these endpoints (file descriptors) - for **every** open pipe - are duplicated.

`read` will block while there is still a chance that incoming data will eventually arrive - meaning, that `read` will block while at least one "output" (writing) file descriptor is still open.

In the following example, I will open a single pipe and fork the process. The forked process will close it's "input" (writing) endpoint and call `read`. `read` will block because there is still one open input fd in the parent process (remember, the `fd` was duplicated). After the parent closes it's "input" `fd`, there are no more writing endpoints and read will fail (stop blocking).

Notice, I'm not writing anything to the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
  int in;   // the input fd
  int out;  // the output fd
} pipe_io;

int main() {
  // the container;
  pipe_io io;
  // make the pipe
  pipe((int*)&io);
  // forking will duplicate the open files
  pid_t child;
  if (!(child = fork())) {  // fork==0 => we're in the child process
    close(io.out);          // closing one reading access point.
    char buff[4];
    // read will block because there's still an open writing access point.
    printf("Child waiting (read will block)\n");
    read(io.in, buff, 1);
    // cleanup and exit process.
    close(io.in);
    printf("Child exits (read stopped blocking once all inputs were closed)\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  sleep(1);  // wait...
  printf("closing parent's writing (output) endpoint.\n");
  close(io.out);
  sleep(1);  // wait...
  printf("closing parent's reading (input) endpoint.\ndone.\n");
  waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
}
```

The output is a clear indication for the code's control flow:

```
Child waiting (read will block)
closing parent's writing (output) endpoint.
Child exits (read stopped blocking once all inputs were closed)
closing parent's reading (input) endpoint.
done.
```

So, in order for a call to `read` to fail (not block), we need to close ALL the writing endpoints/channels.

In your code you had a pipe for every process, but you allowed each process to keep the "input" (writing) endpoint for the other processes open - so `read` would always block.

```
case 0: // the child process
    // This line only closes this process's input stream, but this stream is
    // open for all other processes:
    close(pipes[i][1]); // <- if (i == 2) pipes[1][1] is open. 

    //...

    // `read` will ALWAYS block because other processes keep input endpoints.
    while (read(pipes[i][0], buffer, 127) > 0) {
        //Keep reading and doing nothing
    }
    printf("Dying\n");
    exit(1);
```

You probably meant to write:

```
case 0: // the child process
    // closing all input endpoints (input only performed by root process)
    // also closing all irrelevant output endpoints:
    for (int j = 0; j < PROCESSES; j++){
      close(pipes[j][1]);
      if(j != i)
        close(pipes[j][0]);
    }

    //...
```

---

P.S.

It is less common to open a pipe for every process, unless each process has a separate role.

It is more usual for all processes that share the same function to share the same pipe.

For instance, if a family of processes are used to perform a shared family of tasks, it might not be important which process performs which task - so it would be more effective if the task is submitted to a shared pipe and the first process to read the data is the one that performs the task.

When a process is busy performing a task, it isn't reading from the pipe and if another process is available (blocking on "read"), it is immediately put to work (instead of waiting on the busy process).

This single pipe design minimizes the "waiting" periods and removes any scheduling concerns (except for the limits on the pipe's buffer).

Comment: "After the parent closes it's "input" fd, there are no more writing endpoints and read will fail (stop blocking).", but all the file descriptors are duplicated, this includes presumably `STDIN_FILENO` which is default `1`, but we don't close it in the child, why doesn't this block `read`?

Comment: @demonware - the input endpoints I'm referring to are the ones that write to the same pipe from which `read` is reading. `stdin` isn't writing to the pipe used in `read`, so it's irrelevant. Think about it like species in biology. If there are no more females of a specific specie, that specie will go extinct (assuming females are required for propagation)... having females from other species isn't very helpful ;-)

Comment: Sorry I meant `STDOUT`. Also why would a `pipe[1][1]` possibly affected the read of `pipe[2][0]`, are these not two different pipes?

Comment: @demonware - you are right. Both `stdout` and `pipe[1][1]` have no effect on `pipe[2][0]` (and you really shouldn't name the variable `pipe`, as it's shadowing the `pipe` function)... but - `pipe[2][1]` was left open on the other processes, so that meant `read` was still blocking.

Comment: Oh wait, I understand what you meant, sorry, yes that is completely correct

Answer (score 4):

A few things.

(1) For each child, you were creating only one pipe [parent-to-child], but you need a second one [child-to-parent] (i.e. pipes are *not* bidirectional like sockets).

(2) When you pre-create *all* the pipes, in the child, you have to close the ones that are *not* for the current child, not just the pipe sides for its two pipes.

If you *don't* do this, then child N will hold open the *parent* [and *child*] sides for *each* child's two pipes for *all* children that are *not* N.

*After* a [given] fork, if the parent fully closes an open pipe, the child will *still* inherit [a copy] of whatever file descriptors were open in the parent at the time of the fork. So, closing in the parent has no effect because the *child* is still holding them open--for *all* of the children

That is what your original program did.

In my version [below], it's less severe. Without the preclose (via `childclose`), child 0 holds only its own pipes open. But, Child 1 will hold open child 0's pipes. Child 2 will hold open the pipes for child 0 and child 1.  And, so on ...

So, the many children are holding each others pipe descriptors open. Thus, when the parent process closes the pipes, they are still held open by other children, so *no* child will ever see an EOF

If you'd like to visualize this, take your original code, and as the first executable part of the child after the `fork` (e.g. immediately after the `case 0`) do:

```
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    char buf[100];
    printf("DEBUG: %d\n",pid);
    sprintf(buf,"ls -l /proc/%d/fd",pid);
    system(buf);
}
```

Ignoring stdin/stdout/stderr, instead of the expected 2 (should be 4) open descriptors, you'll see `(2 * PROCESSES)` (i.e. 10) descriptors in *each* child.

After doing the final close in the parent you could repeat such a sequence [in the parent] and you'll *still* see the same thing [minus the two that each child will have closed].

---

This can be more easily organized with a struct. To prove it's actually working, I added some actual data transfer with echo back. I've also added some options for debug to show the differences.

Below, is the corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PROCESSES 5

int opt_n;                              // do _not_ close other children
int opt_p;                              // original semantics
int opt_v;                              // show list

// child control
struct child {
    int cld_idx;                        // child index
    pid_t cld_pid;                      // child's pid
    int cld_status;                     // child's exit status
    int cld_topar[2];                   // pipe: child-to-parent
    int cld_tocld[2];                   // pipe: parent-to-child
};

#define CLOSEME(_fd) \
    do { \
        if (_fd >= 0) \
            close(_fd); \
        _fd = -1; \
    } while (0)

struct child children[PROCESSES];

// fdlist -- output list of open descriptors
void
fdlist(struct child *cld,const char *reason)
{
    struct child cld2;
    char cmd[100];

    if (cld == NULL) {
        cld = &cld2;
        cld->cld_pid = getpid();
        cld->cld_idx = -1;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("fdlist: idx=%d pid=%d (from %s)\n",
        cld->cld_idx,cld->cld_pid,reason);

    sprintf(cmd,"ls -l /proc/%d/fd",cld->cld_pid);
    system(cmd);
}

// childclose -- close any pipe units from other children
void
childclose(int i)
{
    struct child *cld;

    for (int j = 0;  j < PROCESSES;  ++j) {
        if (j == i)
            continue;
        cld = &children[j];
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_topar[0]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_topar[1]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_tocld[0]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_tocld[1]);
    }
}

// childopen -- create pipes for child
void
childopen(int i)
{
    struct child *cld;

    cld = &children[i];

    // to cut down on the clutter, only create the pipes as we need them
    pipe(cld->cld_topar);
    pipe(cld->cld_tocld);
}

// childstart -- start up child
void
childstart(int i)
{
    struct child *cld;
    pid_t pid;

    cld = &children[i];

    // to cut down on the clutter, only create the pipes as we need them
    if (! opt_p)
        childopen(i);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("Error forking a child");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (pid) {
    case 0:  // child
        // close any pipe that doesn't belong to us
        if (! opt_n)
            childclose(i);

        pid = getpid();
        cld->cld_pid = pid;

        if (opt_v)
            fdlist(cld,"childstart");

        // Close the pipe sides we don't need
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_topar[0]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_tocld[1]);

        // Inside the child process, die immediately
        int len;
        char buffer[128];

        while (1) {
            len = read(cld->cld_tocld[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
            if (len <= 0)
                break;

            // Keep reading and echoing
            write(cld->cld_topar[1],buffer,len);
        }

        printf("child %d: Dying\n",i);
        exit(1);
        break;

    default:  // parent
        // give child time to print message
        if (opt_v)
            sleep(1);

        cld->cld_pid = pid;

        // Parent process, close the pipe sides we don't need
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_topar[1]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_tocld[0]);

        break;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    struct child *cld;
    int len;
    char buf[128];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'n':  // do _not_ close other descriptors
            opt_n = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':  // preopen all pipes
            opt_p = 1;
            break;
        case 'v':  // show verbose messages
            opt_v = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    printf("main: pipes will be created %s\n",
        opt_p ? "all at once" : "as needed");
    printf("main: other child descriptors %s be closed\n",
        opt_n ? "will not" : "will");

    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        cld = &children[i];
        cld->cld_idx = i;
        cld->cld_topar[0] = -1;
        cld->cld_topar[1] = -1;
        cld->cld_tocld[0] = -1;
        cld->cld_tocld[1] = -1;
    }

    // create pipes for _all_ children ahead of time
    if (opt_p) {
        for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++)
            childopen(i);
        if (opt_v)
            fdlist(NULL,"master/OPEN");
    }

    // start up all children
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++)
        childstart(i);

    // show final list
    if (opt_v) {
        sleep(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
            cld = &children[i];
            fdlist(cld,"master/POSTSTART");
        }
    }

    // send to child
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        cld = &children[i];
        len = sprintf(buf,"child %d, you are pid %d\n",i,cld->cld_pid);
        write(cld->cld_tocld[1],buf,len);
    }

    // receive from child
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        cld = &children[i];
        len = read(cld->cld_topar[0],buf,sizeof(buf));
        printf("RECV(%d): %s",i,buf);
    }

    // show final list
    if (opt_v) {
        sleep(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
            cld = &children[i];
            fdlist(cld,"master/FINAL");
        }
    }

    // CLOSE ALL PIPES FROM PARENT TO CHILDREN------------
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        cld = &children[i];
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_topar[0]);
        CLOSEME(cld->cld_tocld[1]);
    }

    // AWAIT CHILDREN DEATHS
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        cld = &children[i];
        waitpid(cld->cld_pid,&cld->cld_status,0);
    }

    printf("All children have died\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but why does this cause the `read` in each individual child to block? `read` is on the specific pipe (not all of them) and I do in fact close all of them (from the parent) eventually